# Erro ao compilar projeto Cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake

Estou com o seguinte problema quando tentando buildar um projeto usando CMake:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
```

Estou executando o seguinte: `cmake .`

O erro também diz que eu devia tentar setar as variáveis de ambiente CMAKE_C_COMPILER e CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER para o caminho dos compiladores, então, o fiz. 
Setei as variáveis para `C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe` e `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`, respectivamente.

O erro se manteve.

O meu arquivo CMakeLists contém o seguinte:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.9)
project (hello)
add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)
```

Não tenho nenhum conhecimento de CMake, então, considerem que posso ter esquecido algum passo básico.
Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode estar causando o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri o que estava fazendo errado. Não tenho certeza, porém, do porque não estava funcionando.

Eu não estava selecionando o generator correto, e o seguinte comando resolveu meu problema:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

A partir daí, consegui buildar o projeto como esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que ele não esta encontrando o Compilador de C em seu sistema. 
Pode ser que suas variáveis path não estão corretas.

Para verificar se as variáveis foram setadas corretamente, abra seu prompt de comando e chame o compilador de C. Não lembro qual é o comando para chamar o gcc/g++ pelo terminal. Dê uma busca na web.

Caso tenha tentado e não tenha funcionado, tente setar as variaveis path novamente ou:

Tente reinstalar o MinGW(compilador de C).

Durante a instalação, veja se há opção de setar as variáveis path automaticamente. Depois disso reinicie  a máquina(por precaução) e tente novamente.

Sempre que quiser ver se as variáveis paths estão funcionando, chame o programa pelo prompt.

Comment: Não era este o problema. O compilador estava ok. A resposta abaixo explica o que estava acontendo.